# What is this property called?

Tags: terminology

Let $(V,\,+,\,\cdot\,)$ be a vectorspace and $D\subset V$ a set with the following properties

For $\;\lambda D:=\{\lambda d\mid d\in D\}\;\textrm{ and}\;\;\lambda,\, \mu\ge0$:
$$0\in D$$
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}\lambda D=V$$
$$\lambda<\mu\Rightarrow\lambda D\subset\mu D$$
In other words, the set can be bloated up to fill the entire space.
It would be practical to give this property a name for the paper I am working on, because it is referenced rather often.

Is there a naming convention? If not, what would you suggest?

Comment: You could describe such a set as $V\backslash \mathbb{R}$, but that is of course a description of the set and not the property... IT also seems to be similar to the concept om hypercyclic operators, but with a set instead of an operator, but I guess that doesn't help either.. :-(

Comment: @malin indeed it doesnt help ;) Maybe I will just have to invent a name for it, but I want to check if there is a name for it already

Comment: Related to *absorbing set* as seen here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set

Comment: @GEdgar yup, thats what I was looking for. You can post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to [absorbing set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set) found in wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that $\lambda D\cap\mu D=(0)$ for all $\lambda\neq\mu$? If so, then the name [fundamental domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) is the most common, since it is almost the fundamental domain of $V$ under the $\mathbb{R}$ action.

Comment: oh, I totally forgot about 1 property >_< sorry. I edited my OP. The sets are subsets of one another

Answer (score 1):

The trivial subspace $D=\{0\}$ is the name of your set.

For all negative numbers $\lambda$ you have $\lambda D\subseteq 0D=\{0\}$, so $D=\{0\}$

Or did you mean your properties to hold only for non-negative reals?

In case you restrict to non-negative $\lambda$, wouldn't your condition then just mean that $D$ is a neighborhood of the origin? Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional...

Comment: Agreed ... this is not a good quesiton if negative $\lambda$ are allowed.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I meant only non-negative Integers.

Comment: @ufr, about D being a neighboorhood of the origin, not quite. If D contains a nonempty, open neighborhood of the origin, the properties are fulfilled. GEdgar found that exactly these sets are called "absorbing"